# Issue with hstore when upgrading to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am upgrading an app to rails 4.2 from rails 3.2. While hacking my way through, I get an error relating to Hstore

```
NameError - uninitialized constant 
ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore:activesupport (4.2.6)
lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:533:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
...
```

I currently don't have a gem for hstore as I understand this is native in rails 4.x.

Here's the line in the model that's failing.

```
serialize   :preferences, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
```

What am I missing?

Comment: seems that this line isnt required in rails 4, but try `ActiveRecord::OID::Hstore` or `PostgreSQL::OID::Hstore`

Comment: Thanks. It looks like you are right. This is [not necessary in Rails 4](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore#note-about-rails-4).